# Laravel 6 - can't access attribute in Pivot class

Tags: php, laravel

I have :

- A many_to_many relationship between a `Group` Model and a `User` Model;
- A `Group_User` Pivot class (I need it to observe its events);
- An additional field named `status` in my `group_user` table;
- An observer that observes `Group_User` model.

The setup is as follows

```php
class Group extends Model
{
    /* Other stuff */

    protected $table = 'groups';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
            ->using(GroupUser::class)
            ->withPivot(['status', 'is_confirmed'])
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    /* Other stuff */
}
```

And

```php
class GroupUser extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'group_user';
}
```

In a controller, I have a `$group->users()->attach($user);` (hence creating a new `GroupUser` object and dispatching the `created` event).

In my observer, I have the following piece of code:

```php
public function saved(GroupUser $groupUser)
{
    // Here, I wanted to access $groupUser->status that leads to an error
    dd($groupUser);
}
```

I expected my `$groupUser` to have the `status` attribute as, not only is it in the database, I also specified it in my `users()` function (just to be sure).

---

**EDIT**: here, I meant that when I `dd($groupUser->status);` it returns `null`

---

How can I access this field ?

*Some remarks :*

- I already used in my code `$user->pivot->status` and it works as expected !
- I tried few solutions like explicitly adding `status` to `$attributes` or `$fillable` protected variables of my `GroupUser` class but that had no effect.
- When I dd my `$group_user`, I get:

```php
//...
#attributes: array:4 [
    "user_id" => 1
    "group_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2020-10-12 21:07:53"
    "updated_at" => "2020-10-12 21:07:53"
  ]
#original: array:4 [
    "user_id" => 1
    "group_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2020-10-12 21:07:53"
    "updated_at" => "2020-10-12 21:07:53"
  ]
//...
```

**Finally**, I thought of a hack but I don't quite like it as it seems like a lot of work for such a simple task. I wanted to maybe, add a `getStatusAttribute` function to my model that would return `$this->PivotParent->users()->/*try to make some condition to find the correct user*/->pivot->status;`

Any ideas ?

---

**EDIT 2**: when I pass the extra argument to `attach` it works but I want to use the database default value for the field

---

**EDIT 3**: I found this thread and it made me think that what I want to do is impossible :( I think my `attach` used to work correctly because (and on only because) my SGBD would set the default value for a field that wasn't specified !

---

Comment: Which model is `public function saved(GroupUser $groupUser)` on exactly? Also, when you say "Here, I wanted to access $groupUser->status that leads to an error", what was the error you got?

Comment: `withPivot` isn't adding data to that pivot instance, it is just saying that the retrieved pivot should have that attribute from the pivot table ... you would need to retrieve this record after saving or perhaps add it with the extra arguments to `attach` for other pivot data

Comment: @WesleySmith did not get any error, the `$groupUser` was displayed but WITHOUT the `status` attribute that I need to access ! if I try `$groupUser->status` it returns null (whereas it has a default value)

Comment: @lagbox in saved or in saving it works returns exactly the same array (without the status)

Comment: Oh... I just read `// Here, I wanted to access $groupUser->status that leads to an error`

Comment: @WesleySmith I edited the question so that it becomes clearer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found an answer. It's a bit annoying but it works !

**WARNING**: there is an important remark at the end (edit)

I needed to use `withPivotValue` (link to the [doc](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_withPivotValue), [original pull](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/22867) and [original proposal](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/872)) instead of `withPivot` change my `Group->users()` so my code now is

```php
class Group extends Model
{
    /* Other stuff */

    protected $table = 'groups';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
            ->using(GroupUser::class)
            ->withPivotValue(['status' => MY_DEFAULT_VALUE, 'is_confirmed' => MY_OTHER_DEFAULT_VALUE])
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    /* Other stuff */
}
```

Now that's weird as the doc says :

> Set a where clause for a pivot table column.
> In addition, new pivot records will receive this value.

What's annoying me is that I have to define the default value in two different places, the migration AND the Model. It would be nice if I had a way to synchronize them.

---

**EDIT 1 :** DON'T USE `withPivotValue` in an existing function or it will break your code ! now my `$group->users()` returns only users with the `status` set to the default value so i had to define it in another function called `newUsers` and keep `users` as it was

```php
class Group extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
            ->using(GroupUser::class)
            ->withPivot(['status', 'is_confirmed'])
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function newUsers()
    {
        return $this->users()
            ->withPivotValue('status', DEFAULT_STATUS);
    }
}
```

---

Comment: because `withPivotValue` adds a `wherePivot` condition ... from the docblock for that method: "Set a where clause for a pivot table column. In addition, new pivot records will receive this value."

Answer (score 1):

I created your example in my test environment and I had no problem with the Pivot class not returning the data on the saved observer. Perhaps you have to set the guarded at your pivot class?

```
protected $guarded = []; //accepts all fields to be filled
```

Here are my files

Group.php

```
class Group extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(User::class)
            ->using(GroupUser::class)
            ->withPivot(['status', 'is_verified'])
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

GroupUser.php

```
class GroupUser extends Pivot
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    
        static::saved(function (GroupUser $groupUser) {
            dd($groupUser->toArray());
        });
    }
}
```

And my Unit Test

```
class GroupTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test */
    public function it_belongs_to_many_users()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        $user = factory(User::class)->create();
        $group = factory(Group::class)->create();

        $group
            ->users()
            ->attach($user, ['is_verified' => 1, 'status' => 1]);

        //data will be dumped here by GroupUser::class saved() observer
    }
}
```

here is My Test Output

```
array:6 [
  "user_id" => 1
  "group_id" => 1
  "created_at" => "2020-10-12T20:56:20.000000Z"
  "updated_at" => "2020-10-12T20:56:20.000000Z"
  "is_verified" => 1
  "status" => 1
]
```

I hope that might help you.

Comment: because you are passing the extra pivot data to `attach`, which sets those raw, so they are set on that instance of the pivot model before saving

Comment: thank you @JMoura, but yeah like @lagbox when I passed the extra pivot to `attach` it worked. However, I want it to take the default value set in the database

Comment: @FayçalBorsali you would have to retrieve that pivot record then ... there is no `select` statement happening after an `insert` ... you only have the attributes used to save the record, to get any other fields from the database would require doing a `select` query